# How to sort custom_field in Zendesk Search API

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

This is the API for sorting created date:

```
https://EXAMPLE.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?sort_by=created_at&sort_order=asc&query=custom_field_123:ABC
```

The above API will sort date from ascending and then where under custom_field with ID 123's value = ABC.

But what I need is I want to sort custo_field_123 too. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only sort by `updated_at`, `created_at`, `priority`, `status`, or `ticket_type`. Defaults to sorting by relevance.

Refer to [API reference](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/ticket-management/search/#parameters)